# Does GCP Datastore export reads all entities

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am investigating on the best approach to backuping our data every night. GCP documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities

However I am concerned about this line:
*Entity reads and writes performed by export and import operations count towards your Firestore in Datastore mode costs.*

Does this mean that every night we're going to be reading all records? How expensive can this backuping solution get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes all records will be read. This is quite clear in provided documentation.

You can check [pricing here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing) as well. Fortunately there is Free quota per day, not sure how big is your database...

If you want to estimate all cost of whole your solution you can use very [friendly calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator). If you pick or search for Datastore product it can help you too estimate cost.

If you use other products as well you can add it to total calculation.

I hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is not acceptable and we'll have to invent our own solution of backups. That's a shame.